# Inverter uma pilha usando uma pilha adicional e algumas variaveis

Tags: estrutura-de-dados, stack, pseudocódigo

Estou precisando inverter uma pilha A utilizando outra pilha adicional B e algumas variáveis em pseudo-codigo. Para que a pilha A seja invertido ao fim do algoritmo. Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: A pilha B é obrigatóra? Usando [Bubble Sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) nem chega a ser necessário outra pilha.

Comment: Sim Diego, é obrigatório o uso de uma pilha B e apos inverter na pilha B, utilizar variáveis para retornar os elementos para a pilha A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao empilhar, o último elemento a entrar torna-se o primeiro a sair.
Sabendo disso, basta remover os elementos da pilha ao mesmo tempo que o adiciona em outra.

Pilha A = 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 (Top)

Pilha B;

Pilha A = 5, 4, 3, 2 (Top)

Pilha B = 1;

Pilha A = 5, 4, 3 (Top)

Pilha B = 1, 2;

etc.

Comment: R.Carvalho, eu preciso inverter pra de A para B, porem eu preciso passar invertido para A de maneira que seja invertido de A inicialmente. Ou seja, eu preciso que a pilha A seja invertida utilizando a B e algumas variaveis para que quando ela voltar pra A esteja totalmente invertida

Comment: No fim desse exemplo, voce vai ter a pilha B invertida a A, agora é preciso passar B para A usando variaveis, a ponto que A seja exatamente como B esta agora, invertida.